# Example code for use of DispatcherTime in c++/winrt?

Tags: c++-winrt

Does anyone know of example code to illustrate the creation of a periodic timer, say with DispatcherTimer, in c++/winrt? The examples in the docs are managed C++ and I have not been able to successfully convert them for use with c++/winrt. Thanks...
[Update: in response to popular demand, let me show my own attempts to translate the C++/CX code. Here is the sample code from the DispatcherTimer documentation:

```
void MainPage::StartTimerAndRegisterHandler() {
auto timer = ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::DispatcherTimer();
TimeSpan ts;
ts.Duration = 500;
timer->Interval = ts;
timer->Start();
auto registrationtoken = timer->Tick += ref new EventHandler<Object^>(this, &MainPage::OnTick);}

void MainPage::OnTick(Object^ sender, Object^ e) {
// do something on each tick here ...}
```

//Now, for translating to C++/winrt:

```
void MainPage::StartTimerAndRegisterHandler() {
auto timer = Windows::UI::Xaml::DispatcherTimer(); //that's easy enough
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan(500);    //This can be done in one step, I think
timer.Interval(ts); //And this is easy
timer.Start();  //Seems right
//The following line is the tricky bit.
//I change timer->Tick to timer.Tick
//The following += is described as a way to add a delegate; I drop the ref new
//But Object is not going to work here; it needs to be replaced 
//by, I think, IInspectable const & sender, and probably a lambda
//would replace the OnTick, there is a lot of mystery on this line
//and there hardly seems any point in displaying my several attempts to get past it:

auto registrationtoken = timer.Tick += ref new EventHandler<Object^>(this, &MainPage::OnTick);}
```

So, if anyone has a way to implement that tick handler in cppwinrt I would love to see it. Thanks.

Comment: There is C++/CX sample code in the documentation for [DispatcherTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer). It's unclear, why you are calling that *"managed C++"*. It's also unclear, what you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks, IInspectable - yes, I'm calling that "managed C++," perhaps wrongly. But that code can't be used in c++/winrt, and it's more than just getting rid of the hats and refs. Would be really nice to find an example illustrating how to create such a timer using straight C++ in the cppwinrt environment.

Comment: BTW, I think you should undo the "-1" on the question. The sample code you're linking to is the sample code I'm talking about. Your user name gives me the impression that you work with cppwinrt, so surely you're aware that sample code cannot compile as-is in cppwinrt? All I need, and all perhaps others will need, is an example of how that code might be altered to run in cppwinrt.

Comment: Please take the time to read [ask].

Comment: I had done that, IInspectable. My question was simply whether there is any sample code showing DispatchTimer in c++/winrt. Apparently there is not. But if you guys are willing to look at my attempt to translate the C++/CX code, that's great. I'll add that.

Comment: It appears that what you really are having difficulty with isn't related to the `DispatcherTimer` class at all. It is about registering event handlers. You should probably ask that question instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you are having difficulty registering for a custom event. While C++/CX uses a compact syntax already, C++/WinRT further reduces the amount of code required to set up an event handler.

The `DispatcherTimer`'s [Tick](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer.tick) event handler receives an `IInspectable` parameter. The signature is:

```
void MainPage::OnTick(IInspectable const& sender, IInspectable const& event)
```

Registering the event handler with the `Tick` event is fairly straight-forward as well. Although you can name the [EventHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.eventhandler) class template type of the temporary, there is no reason to do so. Using [uniform initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/uniform-initialization-and-delegating-constructors) syntax, it becomes as simple as calling

```
auto registrationtoken = timer.Tick({ this, &MainPage::OnTick });
```

The code for unregistering the event handler looks like this:

```
timer.Tick(registrationtoken);
```

This looks remarkably similar to the registration code, which I find a bit unfortunate. It'll take a while for your eyes get trained to identify either one.

Note, that while you can use unnamed lambdas with custom event handlers, it is discouraged so as to not introduce circular references.

There is additional information in the official (yet unmaintained) GitHub repository for C++/WinRT: [Registering for events using a lambda](https://github.com/Microsoft/cppwinrt/blob/master/Docs/Migrating%20C%2B%2B%20CX%20source%20code%20to%20C%2B%2B%20WinRT.md#registering-for-events-using-a-lambda). There is also official documentation in the MSDN: [Events; how to author and handle them in C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/events-author-handle).

Comment: FYI: We are in the process of expanding the official documentation on MSDN. Soon that will the authoritative source of information and sample code.

Comment: Thanks very much - that compiles, and also answers my curiosity about the purpose of the registrationtoken. Only catch is that I can't use "auto" as described; the error returned is "A parameter cannot have a type that contains 'auto.' But IInspectable const& does the job. I expect this will function as nicely as everything else has so far in cppwinrt. I think this (combined with Xaml) is the best thing to happen to Windows since moveable windows.

Comment: @RyanShepherd: I have no doubt that you are. And you are doing great, given the circumstances. Inclusion of the C++/WinRT language selector in the MSDN documentation for (part of) the API surface has been a very welcome (although silent) addition. Still, though, is there an official communication channel, where I can drop my prioritized list of must-have and nice-to-have documentation?

Comment: @user3743210: I'm sorry, the `auto` keyword really only works with lambdas. I haven't tested the code, my bad. I haven't worked out, when type deduction works, or why it doesn't in this specific case. I removed it from this answer anyway. If you can confirm, that your real issue was with converting the C++/CX code for event subscription to C++/WinRT, I'll try to edit your question, to be more useful to future visitors.

Comment: @Iinspectable, yes, you are correct- I was asking for sample code in cppwinrt for DispatcherTimer not because I was unaware of the C++/CX sample code, but because I couldn't get my conversion to work - and it was that event subscription that appeared to be the roadblock. Works great now, so I appreciate your help.

Comment: @IInspectable: I've noticed that the documentation pages have "leave feedback" links, and that they appear to be hooked up to https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/winrt-related/issues. I'm not exactly sure where the pipeline goes after that, but Steven White seems responsive there, and he's helping us out with the docs. You could always CC your requests to myself and/or Kenny and we'd be happy to consider them. It's extremely valuable to get the impressions of somebody looking at it from the outside. :)

Answer (score 2):

The [DispatcherTimer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) documentation has sample code that shows how to do this in C++/CX. The C++/WinRT code would be quite similar. The [general-purpose C++/WinRT documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/) should help with any little wrinkles when it comes to converting form C++/CX.

If you've given that a try and there's still a documentation gap, let us know.

(edit 1)

Looks like you've wired most of it up, but are tripping over the event handlers. I agree it's not 100% intuitive the first time, and I'm realizing that our documentation on this topic could be a little more thorough, so here's how this would look to me. Note that this uses all the latest syntax (get_weak) that's already in the preview SDK.

```
void MainPage::StartTimerAndRegisterHandler()
{
  auto timer = Windows::UI::Xaml::DispatcherTimer();
  time.Interval(std::chrono::milliseconds{ 500 });
  timer.Start();
  auto token = timer.Tick([weak = get_weak()](auto const& sender, auto const& args)
  {
    auto self = ref.get();
    if (self)
    {
      self->OnTick(sender, args);
    }
  });
}

void MainPage::OnTick(IInspectable const& sender, IInspectable const& args)
{
}
```

Comment: Ryan, I've updated my question to specify what seems to be the problematic part of the conversion. Thanks.

Comment: @user3743210: I've updated my response accordingly. I now notice that while there are samples of authoring events, our samples for consuming them are a little lacking.

Comment: Ryan, Finally got to trying your code but I find that get_weak() is undefined. What would I have to #include to get access to that?

Comment: Which version of C++/WinRT are you using? It should be defined in the Windows 10 Preview SDK, as well as the final Windows 10 spring 2018 update that goes public April 30.

Comment: Windows Kits/10/bin list 10.0.17083.0 as its latest entry. Not sure if I'm looking in the right place, though, or for that matter how to make sure I have the latest available SDK.

Comment: You can download it from the official site. 17134 is the Spring 2018 update. 16299 was the previous official release. Anything in between is a now-obsolete preview.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk

Answer (score 1):

The current implementation is: [at microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer?view=winrt-22621)

```
...
#include <chrono>
...
void MainPage::StartTimerAndRegisterHandler()
{
    Windows::UI::Xaml::DispatcherTimer timer;
    timer.Interval(std::chrono::milliseconds{ 500 });
    auto registrationtoken = timer.Tick({this, &MainPage::OnTick });
    timer.Start();
}

void MainPage::OnTick(Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& /* sender */,
    Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& /* e */)
{
    // do something on each tick here ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For WinUI 3.0 and C++/winrt, as tested on February 2023, you need to use the Microsoft::UI::Xaml::DispatcherTimer, instead of the Windows::UI::Xaml::DispatcherTimer. Here is the complete code of an error free example...

```
// H file
#include <chrono>

Microsoft::UI::Xaml::DispatcherTimer gTimer{ nullptr };
winrt::event_token gTimerHandlerRegistrationToken;

void CreateTimerAndRegisterHandler();
void UnregisterTimerHandler();
void StartTimer();
void StopTimer();
void OnTick(IInspectable const& sender, IInspectable const& args);


// CPP file
void MainWindow::CreateTimerAndRegisterHandler()
{
    Microsoft::UI::Xaml::DispatcherTimer timer;
    gTimer = timer;
    gTimer.Interval(std::chrono::milliseconds{ 15 });
    gTimerHandlerRegistrationToken= gTimer.Tick({ this, &MainWindow::OnTick });
}

void MainWindow::UnregisterTimerHandler()
{
    if (gTimer) { gTimer.Tick(gTimerHandlerRegistrationToken); }
}

void MainWindow::StartTimer()
{
    if (gTimer) { gTimer.Start(); }
}

void MainWindow::StopTimer()
{
    if (gTimer) { gTimer.Stop(); }
}

void MainWindow::OnTick(IInspectable const& sender, IInspectable const& args)
{
    // do something here, on timer event
    
}
```